# Dúvidas sobre um layout Masonry com linhas verticais

Tags: html, css

Eu preciso desenvolver o seguinte layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu até consegui reproduzir mais ou menos o mesmo comportamento utilizando o plugin [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) e até o momento esse foi o mais perto que eu consegui chegar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os itens não precisam estar dispostos perfeitamente como na imagem, mas eu não consegui descobrir como fazer essa linha vertical entre as colunas chegar até o final. Segue meu código:

**HTML:**

```html
<ul data-masonry='{ "columnWidth": ".menu-item", "itemSelector": ".menu-item" }'>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Administração Pública</a></li>

    <li class="menu-item">
        Healthcare

        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Farma</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Médico-hospitalar</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Prestação de Serviços de Saúde</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Telecomunicações</a></li>

    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Automotivo</a></li>

    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Infra-Estrutura</a></li>

    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Produtos de Consumo</a></li>

    <li class="menu-item">
        Varejo

        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Alimentício</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Moda</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Construção Civil</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Mobilidade Urbana</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Saneamento</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Educação</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Papel e Celulose</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Serviços Financeiros</a></li>

    <li class="menu-item">
        Energia e Recursos Naturais

        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Agronegócio</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Mineração</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Óleo e Gás</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="">Tecnologia</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -32px;
}

ul > li {
  padding-top: 32px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #000;
}

ul > .menu-item {
  width: 20%;
}

ul > .menu-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}

ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ace833;
}

ul > li > ul {
  display: block;
  position: static;
  max-width: none;
  background: transparent;
  top: auto;
  columns: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li > ul > li {
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 10.5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.9;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #777122;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Esses itens vêm de um banco de dados de forma sequencial, então eu só posso usar a lista `ul` em sequencia no HTML.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, ou pelo menos descrever qual o nome dessa técnica de colocar linhas verticais dentro de colunas criadas com lista para que eu possa pesquisar eu mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Um mega menu tem o layout aproximado do que precisa. Segue exemplo: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/YGPJQG

Edit: Relendo seu comentário e prestando mais atenção, sua necessidade é criar uma linha que vai até o final. É difícil saber exatamente como está seu código porque copiando-o, ele fica diferente da imagem que você inseriu.

Acredito que você tenha que definir uma altura para a linha vertical e essa altura precisa ter aproximadamente a mesma altura do seu menu.
Outro detalhe é não esquecer de inserir um **position: relative** na classe pai do menu.

```
ul .menu-item:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -15%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 160px; /* altura total do menu */
}
ul .menu-item:after::last-child{
    background: transparent;
}
```

A segunda sugestão é substituir o **width: 20%**:

```
ul .menu-item {
    /* alterado: */
    width: calc(100% / 5); /* divisão automatica */
    float: left; /* alinhar à esquerda */ 
    position: relative; 
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esse Mega Menu é algum tipo de plugin ou biblioteca?

Comment: Não, esse exemplo utiliza apenas CSS e seria apenas um nome para um tipo de menu que possui várias divisões, fugindo do padrão convencional. Alguns possuem imagens com links.